# Get Region of the video viewers using YouTube API

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm in the research using YouTube-Data-Api. I get like count, comment count like that. I need to get region(Country) list of the viewers of that video one by one in my list. How do I get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, it is only for user who upload the video. In youtube api v3 docs. A url is given something like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={video->id}&key={$key->key}&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status&regionCode=es
```

The part of url in which regionCode is given by you. It is only application if The regionCode parameter instructs the API to select a video chart available in the specified region. This parameter can only be used in conjunction with the chart parameter. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.  For more information You can use this below link.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#chart

Hope it helps you.